# Do we really get that many questions regarding typesetting, that tex is a target for migration?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am a bit baffled that the "other sites" for migration target has tex.se but is missing softwareengineering.se

[image]

Do we really get that many questions about typesetting on stackexchange vs. questions that can be migrated to softwareengineering.se, or unix.se ?

Please bring back the old feature where one could select which site is a valid migration target for trusted users (whatever that could be, 10K+ or 20K+) and leave the static list for others.

Comment: I'd say that we get far more TeX/LaTeX questions that are even worth the time and resources to migrate than we get questions about any other topic that are worth doing so. In other words, in most other topics, the questions are better off deleted anyway because they're just not good enough to be sent over.

Comment: Migration routes aren't a question of volume primarily, but of *reliability* — how sure can we be that we're not migrating garbage? Migrated TeX questions, apparently, are very seldom garbage. Most competing migration routes are pretty unreliable, and in particular SE SE (formerly Programmers) really hates getting bad SO migrations, and has had a lot of them.

Comment: I understand that some questions may not be formulated the right way, but if a question is clearly suited for a different site, even if it is not worded correctly I think higher rep users should be given the option to migrate it (it can then be voted on by other higher-rep users).  In the hope of giving the question the maximum chance to be answered (and corrected) by the appropriate community.

Comment: "[If] a question is clearly suited for a different site [...] I think higher rep users should be given the option to migrate it" -- The problem is that high-rep users from one site aren't necessarily aware of what makes a question suitable for a different site.

Comment: The guidance is don't migrate crud.  To me that means if the question needs to be closed for some other reason besides it being on the wrong site then normally it should just be closed.  Only if the only problem with it is it is on the wrong site then it should be migrated.